# Python 3 - IPAddress check

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip-address

New to python but trying to write something that will check a user entered IP against a CIDR to see which CIDR the IP is within if any... but getting some sort of str version error that makes little sense...

```
import ipaddress

ip2check = input("Enter IP Address:")
blocks = ['192.1.1.1/8', '0.0.0.0/16']
n = 1
print('Scanning through', len(blocks), 'CIDR blocks')
for x in blocks:
    print('Checking', blocks[n])
    breakpoint()
    if ip2check in ipaddress.IPv4Network(blocks[n]):
        print("IP is found in CIDR: ", blocks[n])
    else:
        print("IP not found in", blocks[n])
```

Error:
line 11, in

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py(309)**init**()
> -> def **init**(self, errors='strict')

or maybe its:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_version'

Comment: whats the error

Comment: please paste the command you ran, the full output, and the full stacktrace, without this information it's difficult to help you

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to check the membership of the objec IPv4Network, if you check the overriden **contains**

```py
import ipaddress
import inspect

lines = inspect.getsource(ipaddress.IPv4Network.__contains__)
```

You get

```py
def __contains__(self, other):
        # always false if one is v4 and the other is v6.
        if self._version != other._version:
            return False
        # dealing with another network.
        if isinstance(other, _BaseNetwork):
            return False
        # dealing with another address
        else:
            # address
            return (int(self.network_address) <= int(other._ip) <=
                    int(self.broadcast_address))
```

This means that the object is checking whether the two objects you are comparing have the same version, network type.. etc but what you are doing is comparing a string with a IPv4Network, the piece in **contains** checks the versioning with self._version which the string object does not have, hence the error of 'string object does not have self._version'

In resume: You are comparing an string object with a IPv4Network object which you cannot do.

Comment: If I wasn't clear, the bad line is ```if ip2check in ipaddress.IPv4Network(blocks[n]):```

Comment: hmm oh interesting I had no idea it contained all that other info - so how do I just get out the IP? or is it the network address or broadcast address?